Install a tool on each host in Openstack cluster
I have a tool that monitors network cost on a host, I want to install it in several openstack and kubernetes clusters. The tool needs to be on each host of the cluster. I had no problem in kubernetes since I can deploy it as a daemonset and that's basically all. Is there a way to do something similar with openstack? I'm not very familiar with openstack so the only thing I thought is to write a script and execute it on each host but it would require too much time or maybe openstack heat but I'm not sure if it is the right use case.
Edit: This tool should send data to Grafana via Pyroscope, that also need to be deployed in the cluster

OpenStack does not have any equivalent to a Kubernetes DaemonSet. Your best option is probably to use something like Ansible to automate the process of installing your tool on all the hosts in your cluster.
